# Hiding of HTML element because of its CSS class adv_title

Tags: css, class

I have situation when I have in the code of the page only one input:

```
<input class="adv_title" type="text" name="title" value="<?= $adv['title'] ?>" />
```

and, its hidden!! I removed all CSS includes on the page, I removed all JS includes and its code. And its still was hidden.

So I adventitiously changed css class of the input from 'adv_title' to 'task_title' and the input appeared. **Attention**: there is no no any HTML and CSS and JS code on the page. *So I want to ask*: if anybody met such strange situation when name of CSS class do such trick - hide element without any rules?

[image: view on the front]

[image: html code]

Comment: If you changed the class and it appeared, then it sounds like there **is** CSS on the page.

Comment: Of course there is some CSS on the page. Take a look at dev tools Resources tab.

Comment: Speculating here but...could it be adblock? I see you're using it.

Comment: Your problem is with adblock and its filter lists, the most widely used is [EasyList](https://easylist.to/easylist/easylist.txt). There is one line which is the exact same one as the class you are using. Take a look at that link and try to avoid using names that are listed there.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer is here**: https://easylist.to/easylist/easylist.txt

Thanks to [@pol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6726597/pol) who read the message attentively - reason was adblock rules, there are CSS names which better not use never in the code of the site.

So this question will be useful when CSS classes preparing without adblock, then on production users which uses adblock browser extension(s) can has troubles with such site/service/etc...

*adblock* - is special extension for browsers to block advertising, uses not by all but by a lot of users